# Как сократить данный MySQL-код?

Tags: php, mysql

Можно ли как-то сократить данный код? Думаю, что это делается через циклы, но как - не могу понять.

```
$vel1_res=mysql_query("select * from `tech_char` where name = 'Velo1'");
$vel1=mysql_fetch_row($vel1_res) or exit(mysql_error());

$vel2_res=mysql_query("select * from `tech_char` where name = 'Velo2'");
$vel2=mysql_fetch_row($vel2_res) or exit(mysql_error());

$vel3_res=mysql_query("select * from `tech_char` where name = 'Velo3'");
$vel3=mysql_fetch_row($vel3_res) or exit(mysql_error());

$vel4_res=mysql_query("select * from `tech_char` where name = 'Velo4'");
$vel4=mysql_fetch_row($vel4_res) or exit(mysql_error());

$vel5_res=mysql_query("select * from `tech_char` where name = 'Velo5'");
$vel5=mysql_fetch_row($vel5_res) or exit(mysql_error());

$vel6_res=mysql_query("select * from `tech_char` where name = 'Velo6'");
$vel6=mysql_fetch_row($vel6_res) or exit(mysql_error());

$vel7_res=mysql_query("select * from `tech_char` where name = 'Velo7'");
$vel7=mysql_fetch_row($vel7_res) or exit(mysql_error());

$vel8_res=mysql_query("select * from `tech_char` where name = 'Velo8'");
$vel8=mysql_fetch_row($vel8_res) or exit(mysql_error());

$vel9_res=mysql_query("select * from `tech_char` where name = 'Velo9'");
$vel9=mysql_fetch_row($vel9_res) or exit(mysql_error());

$vel10_res=mysql_query("select * from `tech_char` where name = 'Velo10'");
$vel10=mysql_fetch_row($vel10_res) or exit(mysql_error());

$vel11_res=mysql_query("select * from `tech_char` where name = 'Velo11'");
$vel11=mysql_fetch_row($vel11_res) or exit(mysql_error());

$vel12_res=mysql_query("select * from `tech_char` where name = 'Velo12'");
$vel12=mysql_fetch_row($vel12_res) or exit(mysql_error());

$vel13_res=mysql_query("select * from `tech_char` where name = 'Velo13'");
$vel13=mysql_fetch_row($vel13_res) or exit(mysql_error());

$vel14_res=mysql_query("select * from `tech_char` where name = 'Velo14'");
$vel14=mysql_fetch_row($vel14_res) or exit(mysql_error());

$vel15_res=mysql_query("select * from `tech_char` where name = 'Velo15'");
$vel15=mysql_fetch_row($vel15_res) or exit(mysql_error());
```

Comment: правильно думаете. что то вроде `select * from tech_char where name like 'Velo%'` ну или перечислить все Velo в IN(), если в таблице бывают не только от 1 до 15. Ну и вызываете fetch в цикле

Answer (score 3):

один из вариантов использовать **[IN](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/in-function.php)**:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM `tech_char` 
        WHERE `name` IN ('Velo1', 'Velo2', 'Velo3', и так до 'Velo15')";
$result = mysql_query($sql); 

if (!$result) {
    echo "Что-то пошло не так в запросе ($sql) в БД: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "Ничего не нашёл";
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // какие-то действия, например заполнение общего массива для работы 
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

---

Если надо выбрать все имена, которые начинаются на `Velo` и заканчиваются на что угодно, то можно использовать **[LIKE](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/String_comparison_functions.html)**

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM `tech_char` 
WHERE `name` LIKE 'Velo%'";
```

Остальное как в примере выше.

---

## Напоминаю, что:

> Данное расширение (mysql) устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и удалено в PHP 7.0.0. Используйте вместо него [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) или [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-mysql.php).